# Nature versus science

Tags: worldbuilding-process

Am I right in saying that science can´t explain where everything around us (Nature) comes from (that is to say, things not made by people), but Nature can explain science?

Comment: This seems more of a philosophy question than a Worldbuilding question.

Comment: This question  is either poorly thought out, or not well phrased.  For instance, in what respect is science not part of nature?  And how does 'Nature' actually explain anything?  It just IS.

Answer (score 2):

This is an absolute statement which is not, so far, either correct or incorrect.

So far, science seems to be doing a really great job of explaining (in the sense of coming up with rules which seem to do a good job of making predictions about) Nature (the physical universe), but there are two possible problems. First, of course, science has not yet explained everything. Second, there is no guarantee that, at some point in the future we won't come across things which cannot, by their nature, be explained. For that matter, we may even have come across them already and don't know it.

Nature, on the other hand, does not explain anything to anybody, much less us. To try to translate your statement, "Nature can explain science" seems to mean that the underlying physical relationships and structures of the material universe are sufficient to produce the behavior and thought patterns which we call science. This is (to use an understatement) unproved. Trying to assert it gets you instantly into questions of theology and philosophy, and these are not what you call easy or tractable questions.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you're not careful with your definition of "explain," you can quickly find yourself in a quagmire known as Godel's incompletness theorem.  It shows up when you try to have "science explain science" or "nature explain nature" and you pick too strong of a definition of "explain."  You're absolutely right: the question quickly stumbles into the world of theology and philosophy.

Comment: Isn´t the science that tries to explain science the philosophy of science?